# Android - data binding on a property of an LiveData extended object

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata

I currently started to use the Data Binding Library and in my viewmodel I have an extended LiveData object:

```
public class ScannerViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    /** MutableLiveData containing the scanner state to notify MainActivity. */
    public ScannerLiveData scannerLiveData;
```

**ScannerLiveData:**

```
public class ScannerLiveData extends MutableLiveData<ScannerLiveData> {
    public boolean mScanningStarted;
    public boolean mBluetoothEnabled;
    public boolean mLocationEnabled;

    public ScannerLiveData(final boolean bluetoothEnabled, final boolean locationEnabled) {
        mScanningStarted = false;
        mBluetoothEnabled = bluetoothEnabled;
        mLocationEnabled = locationEnabled;
        postValue(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

**activity_scanner.xml:**

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_test">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="livedata"
            type="de.datacollect.ecount.ui.scanner.ScannerLiveData" />
    </data>
            
    ...
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/state_scanning"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="@{livedata.mBluetoothEnabled ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/recycler_view_ble_devices" />
        ...
```

**ScannerActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityScannerBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_scanner);

    // Create view model containing utility methods for scanning
    mScannerViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ScannerViewModel.class);
    mScannerViewModel.getScannerState().observe(this, this::startScan);
    
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
    binding.setLivedata(mScannerViewModel.scannerLiveData);
    ...
```

How can I bind to the `mBluetoothEnabled` property? I get an unclassified error on build. I already used the search but didn't find something about it. Every help would be appreciate.

Btw:

> Updates to Data Binding:
>
> You can now use a LiveData object as an observable field in data binding expressions. The ViewDataBinding class now includes a new setLifecycle method that you need to use to use to observe LiveData objects.

Comment: What is the specific error? When you remove the visibility expression, do you still get an error?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the LiveData object bind your viewmodel. So change *livedata* variable in activity_scanner.xml to

```
<variable
     name="viewModel"
     type="de.datacollect.ecount.ui.scanner.ScannerViewModel" />
```

and in ScannerActivity

```
binding.setViewModel(mScannerViewModel);
```

Then your binding expression will become

```
android:visibility="@{viewModel.scannerLiveData.mBluetoothEnabled ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}"
```